# What about you?

Tags: sentence-construction

> - Amy: What day is it today?
> - Tom: It's Monday. Hmm... I like Monday.
> - Amy: What do you have today?
> - Tom: We have math, science and art.***What about you?***
> - Amy: We have English and P.E. What do you have tomorrow?
> - Tom: We have art and P.E.tomorrow.
> - Amy: Oh, great.

I can understand that "What about you" means "What do you have today?" 
But I wonder whether "What about you" is an elliptical sentence. If it is, what is the full sentence? If it isn't, how to parse this structure?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not elliptical.  It doesn't have the structure of a canonical clause; it consists of a *wh*-word (either *what* or *how*) followed by a preposition phrase headed by *about*, here meaning "relating to; concerning; on the subject of" (definition from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about)).

Quirk et al. (1985)<sup><sup>†</sup></sup> describe this as a type of irregular *wh*-question, beginning with either *how about* or *what about*.  After these words are either a noun phrase or an *-ing* clause:

> *How about* **some lemon pie?**
>   *What about* **taking the rest of the day off**?

This form of question can be used in two main ways:

1. With directive force:

   > *What about* **following us in your car?**

   This could mean "Please consider following us in your car."  The listener could respond "[Sure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7807/230), I can do that," consenting to the proposition.

   > *How about* **some apple pie?**

   This could mean "Please consider having some apple pie."  The listener could respond with "I'd love some!"
2. To set a topic for inquiry:

   > I'm fine.  *How about* **you?**  Are **you** feeling well?

   This changes the topic from the speaker (*I*) to the listener (*you*).  As in this example, the speaker can ask explicitly about the new topic afterwards.

   Or, as in your example, the listener can answer about the new topic:

   > Tom: We have math, science and art. *What about* **you**?
   >   Amy: **We** have English and P.E. What do you have tomorrow?

   In either case, nothing is omitted.

This construction is used most commonly in conversation in informal English.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>The reference cited here is *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al, 1985).  The relevant section starts on page 839.